# Nginx CDN - redirects to prevent duplicated content

Tags: nginx, cdn

Scenario:

```
Main website: example.com
Static media served from CDN: xxxxx.cloudfront.net (CNAME: cdn.example.com)
```

In an attempt to prevent Google and other indexing bots from indexing the CDN URLs (xxxxx.cloudfront.net and cdn.example.com) and their contents, someone suggested me the following steps:

1) Create a .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} ^.*\.CloudFront\..*$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_cloudfront.txt [L]
```

2) Create robots_cloudfront.txt with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

My questions are:

1) Would that work as expected?

2) How would a translation of the above .htaccess rule look like on Nginx? Not sure if the following is correct:

```
location / {
if ($http_via ~* "CloudFront") {
rewrite ^/robots\.txt$ /robots_cloudfront.txt break;
}
}
```

Thanks!